# Use computer as access point

Tags: windows, wireless-access-point

I want to use a computer as a temporary access point if possible. There is software that claims to do this but what it usually does is provide a wireless router with DHCP+NAT to share internet access.

Is it possible to configure a (Windows) computer to behave as an access point? That is, provide wireless access to the existing network without performing routing/DHCP/NAT (only switching)

Comment: You mean like this: http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot ?

Comment: @JesperJensen No. Windows Internet Connections sharing makes use of DHCP and NAT which makes your computer act like a wireless router instead of a wireless access point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that’s really easy. If you have windows 10, just plug an Ethernet cable into your PC, and find Mobile Hotspot in settings. You can then enter the name and password you want and then enable it. This will make a WiFi network. If you connect your computer to a wireless network instead of an Ethernet cable, then you can turn it into a wireless repeater instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have win 7 machine, then you can create wireless access point without any additional software. Just to network and sharing center and click create new connection, scroll to the bottom of the dialog and click create new adhoc connection and then type in some name and pass. That's it.

Comment: As far as I know this creates an ad-hoc connection instead of a managed  (which is what an AP creates). Internet connection sharing also employs a DHCP and NAT server which makes it very, very different from a wireless AP and more alike to a wireless router.

Comment: What is a "managed" connection here? If one can manage it, then it is    "managed", no?